# Unexpected error keras: "Error: unexpected ',' in:"

Tags: r, keras

I am building a classification model with keras R, and my codes are as follows:

```
model <- keras_model_sequential() 
model %>% 
  layer_dense(units = 256, activation = 'relu', input_shape = ncol(x_train),kernel_regularizer = regularizer_l2(0.001),) %>% 
  layer_dropout(rate = 0.4) %>% 
  layer_dense(units = 128, activation = 'relu',kernel_regularizer = regularizer_l2(0.001),) %>%
  layer_dropout(rate = 0.3) %>%
  layer_dense(units = 2, activation = 'sigmoid')

history <- model %>% compile(
  loss = 'binary_crossentropy',
  optimizer = 'adam',
  metrics = c('accuracy')
)

model %>% fit(x_train, 
              y_train, 
              epochs = 50, 
              batch_size = 128,
              validation_data = (x_val,y_val))
```

Everything is fine but when I tried to pass the outside data (x_val, y_val) to be used as validation data using 'validation_data', then It got this error:

```
Error: unexpected ',' in:
"              batch_size = 128,
              validation_data =(x_val,"
```

If I simply use validation_split=0.2 then all good.
I looked at the codes many times, but could not figure out what is wrong here.
Can somebody help me on this please?

Many thanks,
Ho

Comment: Should it be `list(x_val, y_val)`  You can have a tuple in python

Comment: @akrun: oh, yes it works now, this is not documented on keras website. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is based on the input arguments to be passed.  It should be a `list` as there is no `tuple` in `R` (though it is there in `python`

According to keras documentation

> validation_data - Data on which to evaluate the loss and any model metrics at the end of each epoch. The model will not be trained on this data. This could be a list (x_val, y_val) or a list (x_val, y_val, val_sample_weights). validation_data will override validation_split.

So, we just replace the `(x_val, y_val)` with `list(x_val, y_val)`

```
model %>% 
          fit(x_train, 
              y_train, 
              epochs = 50, 
              batch_size = 128,
              validation_data = list(x_val,y_val))
```